# Cannot Indexing/discover multiple fields in Elassandra

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, elassandra

Trying to create index on multiple fields (discovering 2 fields) in existing Cassandra table as below code.

```
curl -XPUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://x.x.x.x:9200/final_index' -d '
{
  "settings" : {"keyspace" : "keyspace1"},
  "mappings" : {
    "table1" : {
      "discover" : ["to_address", "sent_date"],
      "properties" : {
        "to_address" : {"type" : "keyword"},
        "sent_date" : {"type" : "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZ"}
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

**Error:** "caused_by":{"type":"class_cast_exception","reason":"java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String"}},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required fields need to be discovered as below and remaining fields need to set Index as false.

```
curl -XPUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://x.x.x.x:9200/final_index' -d '
{
  "settings" : {"keyspace" : "keyspace1"},
  "mappings" : {
    "table1" : {
      "discover" : (to_address|sent_date),
      "properties" : {
        "to_address" : {"type" : "keyword"},
        "sent_date" : {"type" : "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZZ"},
        "contact_number" : {"index" : "false"}
      }
    }
  }
}'
```